# HttpClient exception | An error occurred while sending the request vs Unable to connect to remote server

Tags: c#, exception, dotnet-httpclient

I am sending a POST request to a REST API using HttpClient in C#.
When it returns an exception, I noticed the first inner exception message says, `An error occurred while sending the request,` but the InnerException.InnerException.Message says, `Unable to connect to the remote server`

I believe the second one is more meaningful. How can I ensure I can always get the 2nd innerexception message?
I know the chaining won't go that deep for every exception.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in response to your conclusion of the inner exception being more meaningful. You are definitely correct. In most (but not all) cases when inner exceptions are returned, the *innermost exception* has the information that is the most useful.

The reason why the regular exception is most often way less useful than the more inner exception is that the regular exception often is just the API's generic error message. In other words, it's telling you whatever you did went completely wrong, without going into detail at first. Once you start digging down the inner exception(s) you can find the real cause of the exception being thrown.

As you stated in your question the chaining won't go equally deep for every exception, so where you could technically try to get the most inner exception manually, .NET already has us covered with Exception.GetBaseException().

```
ex.GetBaseException()
```

`GetBaseException` will throw the first exception in a chain of exceptions, and depending on where you want to display the exception you could do `.Message` to hide the StackTrace.

```
ex.GetBaseException().Message
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Exception.GetBaseException?view=net-7.0).